# Nested pods ( Cocoapods )

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to do something that I don't know if is right or possible, but is not working.

The scenario is, I have two Swift projects with some nested/hierarchical/shared pods, but some of the pods are ObjectiveC and others Swift. I'm attaching an image to make it easy to understand.

The problem is, the final projects ( ProjectA and ProjectB ) are not seeing the SharedLibrary ( ObjectiveC ) content. Someone already have some similar problem?

[Projects/Pods Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUZUH.png)

- We add this SwiftSharedLibrary, as a way to migrate the legacy ObjectiveC slowly.
- The structure are fully controlled by the cocoapods, and the private projects have configured podspec files with the dependencies.
- Cocoapods 0.39.0 (with the 1.0.0 version have the same problem)
- Using use_frameworks! is all podfiles

Comment: One question that Andrea Murru asked was "It's weird, first of all, did you "`pod update`" on each project?"

Comment: Yes @MichaelDautermann I did, I execute a pod update on each project. I also have tried to remove the Pods directory and the cocoa pods cache.